JavaFX - Updating ProgressBar on Nodes Creation
I've seen a lot of code on the platform regarding updating the ProgressBar using thread, but all of it is related to some calculation performed or updating of some control property. I don't know if it's possible, but what I need is for the ProgressBar to show the progress in creating 225 (15 X 15) to 2500 (50 x 50) TextFields. Below are the files and the .fxml. When I included the thread code part, the grid stopped to appears. Thank you in advance.
The application

GridApplication.java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class GridCenterApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(GridCenterApplication.class.getResource("main-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Grid");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setMaximized(true);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

GridController.java
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class GridCenterController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private ScrollPane scpGrid;

    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> spnCols;

    @FXML
    private Spinner<Integer> spnRows;

    @FXML
    private ProgressBar pgbProgress;

    GridPane gridPane;

    private final int CELL_HORIZONTAL_GAP = 1;
    private final int CELL_VERTICAL_GAP = 1;
    private final int CELL_HORIZONTAL_SIZE = 40;
    private final int CELL_VERTICAL_SIZE = 40;

    private int totalCols = 0;
    private int totalRows = 0;

    @FXML
    void onMnuItemNewGridAction(ActionEvent event) {

        if(!(scpGrid.getContent() == null)){
            scpGrid.setContent(null);
        }

        totalCols = spnCols.getValue();
        totalRows = spnRows.getValue();

        var newGrid = new Grid(totalCols, totalRows, CELL_HORIZONTAL_GAP, CELL_VERTICAL_GAP, CELL_HORIZONTAL_SIZE,
                CELL_VERTICAL_SIZE, pgbProgress);
        gridPane = newGrid.getGrid();
        scpGrid.setContent(gridPane);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
        SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> numberOfCols = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(15, 50);
        SpinnerValueFactory<Integer> numberOfRows = new SpinnerValueFactory.IntegerSpinnerValueFactory(15, 50);
        spnCols.setValueFactory(numberOfCols);
        spnRows.setValueFactory(numberOfRows);
        scpGrid.contentProperty().addListener((observableValue, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue != null && newValue.isVisible()) {
               pgbProgress.setProgress(0);
            }
        });

    }
}

Grid.java
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;

public class Grid {

    private final GridPane grid;

    public Grid(int totalCols, int totalRows, int CELL_HORIZONTAL_GAP, int CELL_VERTICAL_GAP, int CELL_HORIZONTAL_SIZE,
                int CELL_VERTICAL_SIZE, ProgressBar pgbProgress) {

        grid = new GridPane();
        grid.setHgap(CELL_HORIZONTAL_GAP);
        grid.setVgap(CELL_VERTICAL_GAP);
        TextField[][] arrayLetterField = new TextField[totalCols][totalRows];

        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                pgbProgress.setProgress(0);
                double total = totalCols * totalRows;
                double i = 1.0;

                for (int row = 0; row < totalRows; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < totalCols; col++) {
                        arrayLetterField[col][row] = new TextField();
                        arrayLetterField[col][row].setMinSize(CELL_HORIZONTAL_SIZE, CELL_VERTICAL_SIZE);
                        arrayLetterField[col][row].setMaxSize(CELL_HORIZONTAL_SIZE, CELL_VERTICAL_SIZE );
                        grid.add(arrayLetterField[col][row], col, row);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                        updateProgress(i, total);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };

        pgbProgress.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
        new Thread(task).start();

    }

    public GridPane getGrid() {
        return grid;
    }

}

main-view.fxml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Menu?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Spinner?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane prefHeight="767.0" prefWidth="1053.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.gridpanetest.GridCenterController">
    <top>
        <VBox prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
                <MenuBar fx:id="mnuBar" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="360.0">
                    <menus>
                        <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Grid">
                            <items>
                                <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onMnuItemNewGridAction" text="New grid" />
                            </items>
                        </Menu>
                    </menus>
                </MenuBar>
            <Pane prefHeight="80.0" prefWidth="1053.0">
               <children>
                  <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="15.0" text="Columns" />
                  <Label layoutX="26.0" layoutY="46.0" text="Rows" />
                  <Spinner fx:id="spnCols" layoutX="79.0" layoutY="11.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" />
                  <Spinner fx:id="spnRows" layoutX="79.0" layoutY="42.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="57.0" />
                  <ProgressBar fx:id="pgbProgress" focusTraversable="false" layoutX="185.0" layoutY="31.0" prefWidth="200.0" progress="0.0" />
               </children>
            </Pane>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </top>
   <center>
        <ScrollPane fx:id="scpGrid" style="-fx-background-color: #dbbb92; -fx-background: #dbbb92;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
</BorderPane>


Do you want the UI to be updated as new elements are added to the grid? Or all at once after all of the nodes are created?  Also, why add so many grid rows to the UI? Why not use Pagination and/or ListView/TableView?

@jewelsea Hi. I would like to give the user some visual feedback. On my old machine, creating a 50 X 50 TextFields grid takes 7 seconds. So it would be interesting to use a ProgressBar that informs the user at what stage of grid creation the application is at. The grid should be created entirely in memory (as stated in the code) and displayed all at once. In other words, for each TextField inserted in the GridPane, a unit in ProgressBar.setProgress() should be added. The application is for creating crossword puzzles. That is why there are so many TextFields placed in rows and columns.

I was just experimenting with this a little, as I found it a bit surprising it would take that long to create 2,500 text fields. In some quick and dirty experiments (no proper profiling) on my machine (which I admit is quite powerful) it takes less than 0.1 seconds to create the fields and add them to the grid pane. There is a bit of a pause (maybe 0.5-1 seconds) before they appear though. This suggests that the bulk of the CPU time here is in the layout pass. If you want all the text fields to appear at the same time, your progress bar probably won't show the progress during the actual layout

The reason is that the layout pass happens on the same thread that has to update the layout, so the progress bar can't be updated while that is happening. Consequently, the "update grid lazily" example in Sai's excellent answer below probably won't quite do what you want (you'll see the progress bar update relatively rapidly, then a long pause while nothing happens). The "update grid instantly" might be more applicable. That said, you need to properly profile your code to make sure you're not doing something that is causing it to run so slowly.

@James_D The application runs slowly because my laptop is old (14 years old!!! LOL). The pause you mentioned (0.5-1 second) before the grid appears, here is between 6-7 seconds for the 50X50 grid on the first run, dropping to 2 seconds from the second. Honestly, I find the construction of the grid cell by cell "ugly". It looks like the websites from the beginning of the Internet, where a large image, due to the low connection speed, was loaded piece by piece.

@James_D Perhaps to minimize this negative effect I should take a different approach. For example, allow the selection of some ranges of number of cells (20 to 50, in increments of 10) instead of the current way (select any number between these values), leaving two pre-built grids and adapting the number of cells to the user's request (completing or removing cells). I'll think about it and do some tests. BTW, I made the correction in the code you suggested. Thank you so much.

One other thought; the GridPane affords much more flexibility than you need (variable cell sizes, etc), and its layout code is pretty complex in order to achieve that. You know every cell in your grid is the same size. You might be able to use a custom layout strategy that speeds the layout up, though this would be difficult and would take a lot of code profiling. I did a very quick test and maybe got around 6% improvement. Ultimately, though, the way to improve performance here is to create a custom virtualized control (like a two dimensional ListView), but that is very difficult to do.

@James_D I did something very simple that eliminated that pause after the progress bar reaches the end (for you, 0.5-1 second, and for me 6-7 seconds): in the "update grid instantly" code, after creating the GridPane, set it to "grid.setVisible(false);" and in "task.setOnSucceeded" make it visible again. I notice here that the progress bar doesn't update as smoothly as before (but almost unnoticeable), and now the grid appears instantly.

I believe the main problem in your code is the part where you add the text field to the grid. It is because, you are trying to add child node in different thread and not in JavaFX thread.
A quick fix can be wrapping that code in Platform.runLater as below:
int c = col;
int r = row;
Platform.runLater(() -> grid.add(arrayLetterField[c][r], c, r));

But this will not be as the behaviour you want, Because you are adding the grid too early, so you will see the nodes adding one by one..
To update the scrollPane at the end, you can try the below code for getting the desired behaviour. I also included the logic of instant updating of nodes, just for reference to give you some idea.

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class NodesProgressBarDemo extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        TextField cols = new TextField();
        cols.setPrefWidth(100);
        TextField rows = new TextField();
        rows.setPrefWidth(100);
        Button generateLazily = new Button("Generate Lazily");
        Button generateInstantly = new Button("Generate Instantly");
        HBox row = new HBox(20, new HBox(10, new Label("Columns:"), cols),
                new HBox(10, new Label("Rows:"), rows),
                generateLazily, generateInstantly);
        row.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        progressBar.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);

        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setFitToHeight(true);
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);
        VBox.setVgrow(scrollPane, Priority.ALWAYS);

        generateLazily.setOnAction(e -> updateGridLazily(cols.getText(), rows.getText(), scrollPane, progressBar));
        generateInstantly.setOnAction(e -> updateGridInstantly(cols.getText(), rows.getText(), scrollPane, progressBar));

        VBox root = new VBox(10, row, progressBar, scrollPane);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Nodes ProgressBar Demo");
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void updateGridLazily(String col, String row, ScrollPane scrollPane, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        int columns = Integer.parseInt(col);
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(row);

        Task<GridPane> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected GridPane call() {
                int total = columns * rows;
                int count = 0;
                GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
                gridPane.setVgap(5);
                gridPane.setHgap(5);
                for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                        TextField textField = new TextField();
                        textField.setMinSize(40, 40);
                        textField.setMaxSize(40, 40);
                        gridPane.add(textField, c, r);

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                        count++;
                        updateProgress(count, total);
                    }
                }
                return gridPane;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
            scrollPane.setContent(task.getValue());
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
        });
        task.progressProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> progressBar.setProgress(val.doubleValue()));
        new Thread(task).start();
    }

    private void updateGridInstantly(String col, String row, ScrollPane scrollPane, ProgressBar progressBar) {
        int columns = Integer.parseInt(col);
        int rows = Integer.parseInt(row);

        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setVgap(5);
        gridPane.setHgap(5);
        scrollPane.setContent(gridPane);

        Task<Void> task = new Task<>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() {
                int total = columns * rows;
                int count = 0;
                for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) {
                        TextField textField = new TextField();
                        textField.setMinSize(40, 40);
                        textField.setMaxSize(40, 40);
                        int r1 = r;
                        int c1 = c;

                        Platform.runLater(() -> gridPane.add(textField, c1, r1));

                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }

                        count++;
                        updateProgress(count, total);
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        task.setOnSucceeded(e -> progressBar.setProgress(0));
        task.progressProperty().addListener((obs, old, val) -> progressBar.setProgress(val.doubleValue()));
        new Thread(task).start();
    }
}

Related Task Javadoc

A Task Which Modifies The Scene Graph
A Task Which Returns Partial Results


Wow ! Sorry for the huge code, but thank you so much for the help. It's exactly what I need.

It would be slightly more natural to make a Task<GridPane> and just return gridPane, then do scrollPane.setContent(task.getValue()) in the onSucceeded handler. That way you avoid the wrapper (content) you use to get around the scoping problem.

(For the "create lazily" approach, that is.)

@James_D thanks for the suggestion. It makes sense.. updated the code as per the suggestion. :)
